# Aren't all of the following sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, commas

My friend was recently taking a test and couldn't figure out which sentence was correct. This has been bothering me for the past few days because I just can't wrap my mind around which sentence the exam was looking for. Honestly, if I was taking the exam, I would have picked B or C, but I'm open to hearing if I would've gotten it wrong.

A: Try to avoid working in the office alone, but if you must, make sure to keep the front door locked.

B: Try to avoid working in the office alone but, if you must, make sure to keep the front door locked.

C: Try to avoid working in the office alone, but, if you must, make sure to keep the front door locked.

Comment: My personal opinion is that putting a common on either side of a word, like *but* here, is generally bad style. But I don't see any reason to prefer A or B.

Comment: I'd say [B] (_no comma before 'but'_) is pretty unusual. // The comma after 'but' ([B] and [C]} is unnecessary and some would say cluttering. Though correctness/acceptability is often debateable in such cases, I'd choose [A].

Comment: There are already similar questions here, e.g. [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493158/commas-surrounding-and) on "Scout’s father, Atticus, is hired to defend Tom in the trial, and, although it is a lost cause because of the racism of the people of Maycomb, Atticus takes the job seriously and does his best." There seem to be variations in style, with different variants preferred by different people. Take a look around.

Comment: @Stuart I'd guess that dropping the comma from << ... and, although ... >> is a lot more common than dropping it from << ... but, although ...  >> (the contrastive pause is normal. And when it gets to << However, although ... >> ....)